# why natural transformatoins are also called "morphisms" of functors?

Tags: category-theory

I know a category can be described only with arrows, composition, domain and codomain operators.(without objects!)

and a functor just a "morphism"  between two categories, that is, it commutes with three operators above.

so a functor can be veiwed as a category.(it is a "set" just like a function and we can define three operators on it)

however, I cannot understand why a natural transformation is also called a morphism between two functors, how could I think this in the similar way naturally?

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is in Exercise I.4.5 of *Categories for the working mathematician*.

Answer (score 3):

Given two categories *C* and *D*, there is a category *Fun*(*C*,*D*) whose objects are functors from *C* to *D*, and where the morphisms from a functor *F* : *C* → *D* to another functor *G* : *C* → *D* are the natural transformations from *F* to *G*. (You might enjoy the exercise of verifying this does form a category, with the usual composition of natural transformations.

Comment: thank you but that's not my question. my question is how to define natural transformation in a "(homo)morphism" way

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that what I wrote is _the_ reason people call natural transformations "morphisms of functors", @user223790. I'm not sure the concept of being "homomorphism-like" really makes a lot of sense, but if you want to classify categories by what their morphisms "feel like", I'd say natural transformations are much more like homotopies than like homomorphisms.

Comment: There is a precise sense in which they can be viewed as homomorphisms: when $\mathcal{C}$ is small and $\mathcal{D}$ is locally presentable, then $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{D}]$ is also locally presentable, so you really can think of functors $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ as certain mathematical structures in that case.

Comment: That's a good point, @ZhenLin and it might be exactly the sort of thing the OP is looking for. I'd suggest you write an answer giving some familiar examples, like taking C to be the Lawvere theory for groups, D to be Set (and restricting to product preserving functors), etc.

Comment: the conceptions of functor and natural transformation are similar? can we give the definitions inductively?